# Comma after 'so'?

Tags: commas

Is a comma needed after 'so' in this sentence: "So are you going to get it?" If a comma is/isn't needed, I would love a small brief explanation as to why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be an accidental duplicate. Here's a link to another thread full of great answers that are better than mine: [When do we need to put a comma after "so"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30436/when-do-we-need-to-put-a-comma-after-so?rq=1)

I'll add my two cents though. To me this sounds like it relates to day-to-day conversation.

The brief pause after "so" with the use of a comma -- in my mind -- would seem to subconsciously suggest a bit of suspense. As an example: if I'd just got in a spat with my younger brother about running errands and I'd thought I'd won the argument, I might say it as, "... So, are you going to get it?" (whatever 'it' is)

Now, if I was *really* excited about a video game and trying to convince my friend to buy it, after telling him why he should get it, I might say it without the comma. "So are you going to get it?"

It's contextual if you ask me. Not so much a grammar thing as far as I know, in this specific case. More about how you want it to sound.

Comment: Caution: 'so,are you' is a question, but 'so are you' is a statement (fragment), perhaps in response to 'you are cute'.  In speech the pause may be omitted because the context is clearly adverbial, but in writing, the comma after 'so' marks the end of the adverbial, preventing a 'garden path' interpretation.

Comment: Good catch; cheers! ^